# How do I set a dependency on Spring Web Services in my POM.xml

Tags: web-services, spring, maven-2, spring-ws

I get this on a lot of Maven dependencies, though current source of pain is Spring.

I'll set a Spring version and include it like so:

```
 <spring-version>3.0.0.RELEASE</spring-version>

 <!-- Spring framework -->
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

Which works as expected.

I am however having problems setting my dependency on spring-ws-core for web services.  The latest I can find in any repo is 2.0.0-M1.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ws/spring-ws-core

Any clues on what I need to include in my maven POM to get Spring 3 web services to work :)

Answer (score 8):

Well, 2.0.0-M1 is simply the latest version of spring-ws-core.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-M1</version>
</dependency>
```

And actually, the current stable version is 1.5.9.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay,

don't know too much about maven. But spring source have a repository which has maven access at:-

http://www.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=org.springframework.web&version=3.0.2.RELEASE

Looks like the maven stuff is

```
<dependency>  
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>    
 <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>  
 <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>
```

But, again, i use ivy not maven!

Edit:

Oh and instructions for adding maven repository stuff are in the faq at http://www.springsource.com/repository/app/faq#q8.

Comment: Thanks very much - gets me further, but I'm not able to pick up an important class when I do this - 

package org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint does not exist

Any clues on how to find which spring module I need to include in Maven to get this guy? 

Thanks

Comment: With ivy, it's easy it automatically does the transitive stuff! There must be an equivalent mechanism in maven?

http://www.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=org.springframework.ws.java5&version=1.5.9.A

This one seems to export that endpoint package...

Comment: You can expand the required dependency bit to see what it all depends on.

Transitive dependencies can suck a lot more in, so make sure you just use the scope/configuration that you actually need!